# Как подписать/зашифровать, если недоступен openssl  в php?

Tags: php

Возможно существуют готовые библиотеки или способы/алгоритмы. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/crypt/examples.html